# Why fetch() does not work?

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm trying to fetch a collection from a JSON url. The backbone does send the request and does get a response but there are no `models` in the collection after it:

Here is my JavaScript:

```
stores.fetch();
```

JSON in the response

```
[{"name":"Store 1"},{"name":"Store 2"},{"name":"Store 3"},{"name":"Store 4"}]
```

The Content-Type HTTP header in the response is `application/json`.

Why doesn't it load into the collection? Is the JSON correct?

Some more code:

```
be.storeList.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        description: null
    },
    initialize:function(attrs){
        attrs.id = this.cid;
        this.set(attrs);
    }
});

be.storeList.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: be.storeList.Item,
    url:'/admin/stores'
});

var stores = new be.storeList.Items();
stores.fetch();
console.log(stores.toJSON());
```

Comment: share a bit more code please, is the JSON url on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, the backbone does send the request and does get a response.

Comment: can we see all your code.  without seeing it, it could be many things - are you overriding the parse method?  how do you know the data isn't in the collection?  are you using the get("name") method to see that, or mistakingly calling x.name?

Comment: console.log(stores.models) == []

Comment: `fetch`is asynchronous. Try `stores.fetch({ success:function() { console.log(stores.toJSON()); } });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch`is asynchronous. Try

```
stores.fetch({ 
    success:function() {
        console.log(stores.toJSON());
    }
});
```

or

```
stores.on("sync", function() {
    console.log(stores.toJSON());
});
stores.fetch();
```

or

```
stores.fetch().then(function() {
    console.log(stores.toJSON());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the initialize function in your Item class.  You don't need it.

There's no such thing as `stores.models` -- if you want to see what's in it, you have to do `console.log(stores.toJSON());`

Comment: There's no such thing as stores.models  -- if you want to see what's in it, you have to do console.log(stores.toJSON());

Comment: There is, and it's in the backbone.js documentation to the collection. Besides, this works just fine: var stores = new be.storeList.Items([{"name":"Store 1"},{"name":"Store 2"},{"name":"Store 3"},{"name":"Store 4"}]);