# Getting Data out of a postgreSQL database with backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, backbone.js

So can't get these albums rendered(in a rails index list fashion) with backbone that are persisted into my postgres db:

```
 [#<Album id: 1, title: "abbey road", artist: "the beatles", created_at: "2013-05-24 20:35:44", updated_at: "2013-05-24 20:35:44">, #<Album id: 2, title: "Random Access Memories", artist: "Daft Punk", created_at: "2013-05-24 20:36:14", updated_at: "2013-05-24 20:36:14">, #<Album id: 3, title: "Illmatic", artist: "Nas", created_at: "2013-05-24 20:36:51", updated_at: "2013-05-24 20:36:51">]
```

**Server side my index method is standard`**

```
  class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
```

**and routes are configured the same**

```
resources :albums
```

**Client side my backbone part to render the albums looks like this**

```
app.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['templates/home'],

    render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template());

    // Find all the albums in the system
    var albums = new app.collections.AlbumList();
    albums.fetch();
    console.log(albums);
    var _this = this;

    albums.fetch({
      success: function(albums, response, options) {
        albums.forEach(function(album) {
        _this.$el.find("#albums").append("<li><a href='#' class='album-link' data-id='" + album.id + "'>" + album.title() + "</a></li>");
        });
      }
    });

    // Add a <li> element containing a link to each profile page
    return this;
  },

});
```

**Heres the AlbumList collection**

```
app.collections.AlbumList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: app.models.Album,
  url: '/albums'

});
```

**Yet when console log albums, its an object with 0 length**
Am I forgetting a step here to link it to the database? Thanks!

**Further this is the GET request the server is sending**

```
Started GET "/albums" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-25 09:13:00 -0400
Processing by AlbumsController#index as JSON
  Album Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums" 
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Which if the above SQL query in the console manually, will retrieve the correct info.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619836/why-fetch-does-not-work/10620694#10620694

Comment: Thanks!  An informative link but I still get the objects out of my db

Answer (score 1):

The server wasn't sending any information back.  Configuring it to respond with JSON solved it like so:

```
  def index
    @albums = Album.all

    render :json => @albums
  end
```