# backbone .fetch() not loading json file

Tags: backbone.js

I'm very new at Backbone and I need some help.

Below is the code I'm currently working with and then the a sample of the json file.

When I load, the console gives me any empty object (0 models)

Here is the backbone file:

```
ContactManager.module("Entities", function(Entities, ContactManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

    Entities.Paragraph = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  Entities.Paragraphs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Paragraph,
    url: "jsonTest.json"
  });


  var paragraphs
  var initializeParagraphs = function(){
    paragraphs = new Entities.Paragraphs;
    paragraphs.fetch();
    console.log(paragraphs)

  };

  var API = {
    getParagraphs: initializeParagraphs
  };

  ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("paragraph:entities", function(){
    return API.getParagraphs();
    });
});
```

Here's the Json

```
[
        {
            "id" : "l18-seqtfp",
            "itemid" : "lectio18",
            "text": "Sciendum est quod in praecedentibus tactum est quod ipsa fides iuvat lumen naturale ut attingere  possit   veritates theologicas, quia sine fide lumen naturale non sufficit ut pertingere  possit   ad huiusmodi veritates theologicas, iuvamine tamen fidei potest.",
        },

        {
            "id" : "l18-rinamd",
            "itemid" : "lectio18",
            "text": "Restat igitur  pro   nunc consequenter  inquirere   modum per quem fides confert ad  theologicas veritates    inquirendum,    et in ista lectione faciam finem de materia fidei et processus theologici in lumine naturali et veniam ad  materiam   distinctionum.",
        },

        {
            "id" : "l18-pctssa",
            "itemid" : "lectio18",
            "text": "Pro cuius tamen materiae  declaratione   ponam istam conclusionem, quamvis fides non  intret   processum theologicum tamquam pars antecedentis theologicam conclusionem probantis, ipsam tamen requiritur ad sic scientifice assentiendum.",
        },
]
```

Again, when the console logs paragraphs I just see any empty collection object. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit -- I modified the fetch to return a response on error or success, and it seems to be responding to "error" so, for some reason, my fetch is returning an error.

thanks

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619836/why-fetch-does-not-work/10620694#10620694

Comment: I tried those answers, no success. Dev-tools tells me the request to the json file is succeeding, so something must be happening that prevents the data from being loaded into the collection object

Comment: Well I don't really understand this, but change the spacing in my .json file made the difference. I guess there were extra hard returns and new lines that make a difference. The json file I'm using was generated from XML using XSLT. I removed extra white space, and the fetch worked. I guess the lesson is white space matters!