# Converting Backbone model to JSON set default values

Tags: json, backbone.js, underscore.js

This is my Backbone model code where I set the default values.

```
App.Models.Stock = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name:       '',
        quantity:   0,
        booked:     0,
        minimum:    0,
        active:     1
    },
    urlRoot: '/stock/'
});
```

And this is my Backbone view code where I'm waiting for button clicks.

```
templateItem: _.template($('#stockItem').html()),
events: {
    'click #openStock': 'showStock'
},
showStock: function(e) {
    var stock = new App.Models.Stock({
        id: $(e.currentTarget).data('id')
    });
    stock.fetch();
    $('#sidebar').empty().append(
        this.templateItem(stock.toJSON())
    );
}
```

The problem is that when we fetch the model the server returns the proper result, but when I try to convert it to JSON, Backbone set default values for the model! Why does it happen? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Really looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619836/why-fetch-does-not-work/10620694#10620694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your `stock.toJSON()` into a callback of `fetch`. `Fetch` is asynchronous, so the values from your server are not loaded until after you call `stock.toJSON()`.  At that point, the defaults are still set on `stock` rather than the values you loaded from the server.

Try...

```
stock.fetch({
    success: function() {
        $('#sidebar').empty().append(
            this.templateItem(stock.toJSON())
        );
    }
});
```